# I got storage account 'Storage', which is not defined. error Running Azure Function docker locally

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm stuck with the error below when I'm trying to generate APK using flutter on Azure docker image locally

what is this error? will it be there on production also or this just local image limitation?

> warn: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ChangeAnalysis.ChangeAnalysisService[0]
>         Breaking change analysis operation failed
>   System.InvalidOperationException: **The BlobChangeAnalysisStateProvider requires the default storage account 'Storage', which is not defined**.
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ChangeAnalysis.BlobChangeAnalysisStateProvider.GetCurrentAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /azure-functions-host-0cf47580569246787259ef2a29624cf9e8ce61b0/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/BreakingChangeAnalysis/BlobChangeAnalysisStateProvider.cs:line 40
>      at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ChangeAnalysis.ChangeAnalysisService.TryLogBreakingChangeReportAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /azure-functions-host-0cf47580569246787259ef2a29624cf9e8ce61b0/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/BreakingChangeAnalysis/ChangeAnalysisService.cs:line 92

Answer (score 4):

> On any plan, a function app requires a general Azure Storage account,
>   which supports Azure Blob, Queue, Files, and Table storage. This is
>   because Functions relies on Azure Storage for operations such as
>   managing triggers and logging function executions

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#storage-account-requirements

All Azure Function apps require an Azure Storage account to run.  When you deploy to Azure you will have to provision a storage account (the Azure Portal will take care of this for you when you create the Function App resource).

When running locally typically you use the [Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) and the following setting in your `local.settings.json`:

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
```

Comment: How might I set this value in the code? I'm deploying an azure function via azure container instance. I'm not sure how i'd set that.

Comment: Figured out I can set it by defining the environment variable `AzureWebJobsStorage`

Answer (score 2):

It happens while deploying the docker image (*Azure Function Apps*) with AzureWebJobsStorage into Azure container instances.

In local environment, it is alright to leave it as `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`

We need to define AzureWebJobsStorage with real Azure storage connection string in release definition or in the target container instance.

It solved my problem. Crhistian Ramirez has also outlined the same fix. I am adding this answer for other's notice.